# How to write a template that can deduce a type use a function's argument type?

Tags: c++, templates

How to write a template that use function as template parameter, and auto deduce other typename by this function's argument type?

```
void foo(int *p) {}

template<typename T, void (*F)(T*)>
struct bar
{
    bar(T* t)
    {
        F(t);
    }
}

int *p;
bar<int, foo> b(p); // both int and foo are required here
```

how to write a template that supports to use only `foo` as argument

```
bar<foo> b(p);
```

Comment: As near as I can see (admitted not very close), you can't. `T` is in a non-deducible context.  You may be able to make `F` a typed template argument (as opposed to the non-typed you have now) then move the deduction to the constructor by templating that. I'd have to think about it for awhile. And even in that case you would need a decltype on the decl of `b`.

Comment: You need an `auto` template parameter which requires C++17.

Comment: @n.m. If you mean `template<void (*F)(auto)> struct bar`, then g++ gives me `error: ‘auto’ parameter not permitted in this context`

Comment: No this is not how auto works. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f589f17e8bfd766 is one way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. that works, but it will be better if without c++17. Prefer c++11 > c++14 > c++17

Comment: You can't do it without C++17 (or ugly macros).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get argument type of template callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630832/get-argument-type-of-template-callable-object)

Comment: @n.m. This is possible for C++11.

Comment: @Robert please go ahead.

Comment: Updated answer. Didn't get it to work as a template parameter - only as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use c++17 with it's auto template parameter (like @n.m. said in the comments) you can use it as the template parameter and then the type T with type traits.

First off we need the standard type traits and also a type trait to get the argument to a unary function (your foo) that we can write like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Trait to get the argument type of a unary function
template<typename T>
struct unary_func_arg;

template<typename R, typename T>
struct unary_func_arg< R(*)(T) >
{
    using type = T;
};
```

This will produce an error if you put anything other than a function pointer into it since the main specialization is not declared.

After this we can finally write bar as this:

```
template< auto F >
struct bar
{
    // Assert it's a function pointer
    static_assert( std::is_pointer_v<decltype(F)> );
    static_assert( std::is_function_v< std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(F)> > );

    // Get the parameter type
    using T = typename unary_func_arg< decltype(F) >::type;

    bar(T t)
    {
        F(t);
    }
};
```

We have to make sure that F is a function pointer so we static assert that, then we get the type T from our type trait.

Now you can declare f and b like this:

```
int* p;
bar<foo> b(p);
```

EDIT: If you need T to be not a pointer so you can write T*, you can either make a type trait that removes 1 pointer level or modify the type trait here to as such:

```
// Trait to get the argument type of a unary function
template<typename T>
struct unary_func_arg_pointer;

template<typename R, typename T>
struct unary_func_arg_pointer< R(*)(T*) >
{
    using type = T;
};
```

Now T will be just int in this example

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 classes cannot deduce all the types of a passed function. But a function can.
So this function can be written:

```
template<typename Ret, typename Param>
Deduced_Types<Ret, Param> deduce_type(Ret (*)(Param))
{
    return Deduced_Types<Ret, Param>();
}
```

This function uses a type to store the deduced types (it has to be declared before the function):

```
template<typename Ret, typename Param>
class Deduced_Types
{
public:
    typedef Ret Return_type;
    typedef Param Parameter_type;
};
```

Now to test it;

```
int f(bool)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    decltype( deduce_type(f) )::Return_type i = 0;

    return i;
}
```

It works.

So Now to Bar:

```
template< class F >
class Bar
{
public:
    typedef typename F::Return_type Func_Return_type;
    typedef typename F::Parameter_type Fun_Param_type;

};
```

which has to be called:

```
Bar< decltype(deduce_type(f)) > b;
```

(this is where You can use a macro)

Works on gcc 4.8.1 : https://godbolt.org/z/1cz2pk

---

Edit:

Pre C++17 function could not be passed into a template.

So what is needed is that you need to pass the function pointer into the class. And a `static_assert` to verify the parameters are correct:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct bar
{
    template<typename F, typename T>
    bar(F f, T t)
    {
        typedef decltype(deduce_type(f)) D;
        static_assert(std::is_same<typename D::Parameter_type, T>::value,"parameter has different type function parameter");

        f(t);
    }
};
```

Now instead of passing the function as a template parameter, the function pointer is passed in as a parameter:

```
void foo(int *p) {}

int *p;
bar b(foo, p);
```

Only problem here is that the class has to store this pointer for future use.

Comment: I think the point of templating on the function pointer itself and not on the type was to generate a unique template for every different function that's put in, this wouldn't do that, since it's templated on the function type, because else he could just change the declaration to `template<typename F>` and use it as `bar<decltype(foo)>`, and then extract T from the type F.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, you might do

```
template <auto> struct bar;

template<typename T, void (*F)(T*)>
struct bar<F>
{
    bar(T* t) { F(t); }
};
```

with usage:

```
int* p = nullptr;
bar<foo> b(p);
```

Prior C++17, you might do:

```
template <typename T, T> struct bar;

template<typename T, void (*F)(T*)>
struct bar<void (*)(T*), F>
{
    bar(T* t) { F(t); }
};
```

With usage:

```
int* p = nullptr;
bar<decltype(&foo), &foo> b(p);
```

MACRO can be used to remove duplication such as:

```
#define BAR(Func) bar<decltype(&Func), &Func>
#define TYPE_AND_VALUE(V) decltype(V), V>
```

to allow:

```
BAR(foo) b(p);
bar<TYPE_AND_VALUE(&foo)> b(p);
```